# Set font in comment

Tags: excel, vba

I add some lines in a cell comment, so there i need the Font "Courier New".
But i also need some more specific sets like font and size.

```
Sub SetCommants()
With Cells(4, 8)
    If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Visible = False
    .Comment.Text Cells(1, 3) & Chr(10) & Cells(1, 4) & Chr(10) & Cells(1, 5) & Chr(10) & Cells(1, 6)
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End With 
End Sub
```

Which lines i had to insert in my code to set the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Sub SetCommants()

    Dim ar
    ar = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("C1:F1")))
    
    With Cells(4, 8)
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = False
        .Comment.Text Join(ar, vbLf)
        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            With .Characters(1).Font
                .Color = vbRed
                .Name = "Courier New"
                .Size = 16
                .Bold = True
                .Italic = True
            End With
            .AutoSize = True
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```